# Utilizar Child process spawn en Node JS y guardar datos en variable

Tags: javascript, nodejs

La idea es ejecutar un comando y capturar la respuesta en una variable para poder procesarla.

```
const { stdout } = require('process');

function files(command, arg) {
    const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    const ls = spawn(command, [arg, '/home']);
    ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
        return data;
    });
}

var ej = files("dir", "")
console.log("eje => " + ej);
```

Al ejecutar la siguiente linea se obtiene:

> ```
>  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
>
>     stdout: /home/test/Descargas: a.jpg  link.txt
> ```

Al intentar retornar el valor aparece indefinido

> ```
> return data; 
> console.log("eje => " + ej);
>
> eje=> undefined
> ```

Comment: Si una de las funciones que estas utilizando es asincrona necesitaras utilizar await porque si no te retornara la promesa siempre en vez de la resolución de la misma

Comment: Fue muy util tu comentario, voy a subir la correcion utilizando **spawnSync**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codigo con correciones:

```
 const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');
    
    function files(command, arg, path) {
        const ls = spawnSync(command, [arg, path], { encoding: 'utf8' });
        return ls.stdout;
    };
    
    
    var ej = files("dir", "", '/home/test/Descargas');
    console.log("eje => " + ej);
```

Salida

```
eje => /home/test/Descargas: a.jpg  link.txt
```